# "package solana-program v1.18.7 cannot be built" error

Tags: solana-program, rust, program, build-bpf, rustc

I have a new Rust project that gives the following error when I compile it.

```
package `solana-program v1.18.7` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.72.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.7 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Hey! Can you add a snippet of your Cargo.toml file + Solana CLI & Anchor CLI versions? That'd help with pinpointing the issue :)

Comment: What I don't understand is the Rust version on my own computer is 1.76.0, but why it gives such an error. anchor-cli -> 0.29.0, solana-cli -> 1.17.25

Comment: The error isn't pertaining to the rust version on your computer, but rather the rust version associated with another dependency or the Solana CLI. I'd try updating the Solana CLI to 1.17.27 to see if that fixes the problem. If not, I'd probably need to see what dependencies you're working with from Cargo.toml

Answer (score 1):

From the [Solana Rust Getting Started Guide](https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/local-rust-hello-world):

> It is highly recommended to keep your solana-program and other Solana Rust dependencies in-line with your installed version of the Solana CLI. In your case, since you are running Solana CLI 1.17.25, you can run:

```
cargo add solana-program@"=1.17.25"
```

> This will ensure your crate uses only 1.17.25 and nothing else.

Comment: thanks it worked